# Named parameter within options

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to set up deep linking on one of the pages of my react application. I want to support the following links:

```
/messanger
/messanger/attachments
/messanger/messages
/messanger/messages/123
```

I tried the following regex:

```
/messanger/:selectedTab(attachments|messages/:messageId?)?
```

but the nested `/:messageId?` does not seem to be valid syntax. I could do:

```
/messanger/:selectedTab(attachments|messages)?/:messageId?
```

but that would allow:

/messanger/attachments/123

which I do not want. The [docs](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) do not seem to cover this use case.